# Can't access locally hosted project via the internet?

Tags: java, servlets, port, lan

I'm currently developing  a Java Servlet Project in Eclipse. The project is compiled via Tomcat 5.5 and hosted in `localhost:8080`(alternatively `127.0.0.1:8080` AND `192.168.1.10:8080` which also happens to be my local IP). The hosted project can be accessed on another computer via my Intranet(Local Network) at `192.168.1.10:8080`. It should be mentioned that my computer is behind a router, and, I've configured it to forward the port `18261` to `192.168.1.10:8080`. Yet, when I access the project via a web based proxy and enter: `{my IP Address}:18261` then, it gives a error message.

Comment: plz transfer this question to ServerFault.

Comment: you should've put the Update as an answer

Comment: @medopal   
Request Fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the port `8080` in your router, if you don't know how to open a port I suggest you to check [PortForward](http://portforward.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]

I've now resolved the problem. It turned out, that for some reason, the router wasn't forwarding the port `18261` to `8080` so, the next time I entered: `{My IP Address}:8080` in the web based proxy, and, it Worked!! (but I don't know why!)